# Generate pca plots in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, pca

I have data set with 900 rows and 90 columns.i have done the PCA while generating PCA plots unable to analysis due to overlapping of row names.i want to do analysis of PCA and need to get the results based on row name .
plot:[image]

Comment: done, i want to analyze those are in black !

Comment: Ok, so as I suppose, this is the PCA based on results from miRNA-seq or expression microarray. As far as I know it should be plot of samles instead of miRNa, because the point of PCA is to distuinguish some similarities betwenn samples based on mirNA expression. Summarizing I son;t get it why there are points representing miRNAs? Could you show a code generating PCA data and plot?

Comment: @Adamm c1<-princomp(log(pcdatarem,cor = TRUE,score=TRUE))
  summary(pc1)

Comment: Hey @hsbioinfo , is this what you really used? c1<-princomp(log(pcdatarem,cor = TRUE,score=TRUE)). The cor and score should be outside the log bracket, meaning princomp(log(..),cor=TRUE,score=TRUE)

Comment: And also, you have done a pca on the observations (rows), and what would you like to do with them now? You want to plot such that every label can be seen.. might be a bit hard to read 900 labels?

Comment: yes i want to plot in such way that maximum label can be analyzed @StupidWolf

Comment: hey it's almost impossible to make or make something that can be read... i don't know what you mean by analyze, so sometimes you can use geom_text_repel, https://www.biostars.org/p/181211/, but.. not for 900 observations honestly..